# how to plot amplitude and phase of IMDs from their fft values?

Tags: fft

i have my output as vector of 60000 complex number representing 10 sequence in frequency domain , each of length 6000. i need to plot the phase and amplitude of intermodulation distortion from this output. can anyone suggest me how it can be done. i tried with magnitude and angle unwrap in matlab selecting particular bins in a particular sequence where the IMD tones are located but it seems its not working. Can anyone offer a different approach? ITS urgent :(

Comment: In what way is it "not working" ? If you plot the spectra can you see peaks corresponding to the IMD frequencies ?

Comment: yes !! when plotting the spectra everything is perfect. the problem is what shall i take as amplitude and phase of the IMD and how

Comment: Amplitude should be simple enough - it's just the magnitude of the peak. Phase is tricky though - you'll first need to define exactly what you mean by phase, i.e. phase of the IMD component relative to *what* ?

Comment: actually my final goal is to find the phase relationship between the IMD3 products and the fundamental frequencies, so i suppose it will be phase relative to o/p fundamentals.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the application area ?

Comment: I'm doing a paper on characterization of memory effects in power amplifier with multi tone measurements and got stuck here....thanks :)

Comment: Plotting phase can produce nonsense plots easily because the noise components that are close to 0 amplitude have random phase.  You probably want to threshold only the frequencies with large amplitude peaks, and plot the phase of only those frequencies?  What are the test tones you're stimulating the system with?  Sounds like a multitone test?  But multitone signals [generally have random-like phase themselves](https://gist.github.com/endolith/5322734), so I'm not sure what you're going to measure the phase relative to.

Comment: actually i wanted to plot the phase and amplitude of 3rd order IM products relative to fundamentals tones